# Change a 30in range hood with a 36in hood

Tags: exhaust-fan, hood

I recently bought a house and the previous owner had a 30in Nutone hood over a 36in Range. the range is vented horizontally(it is an under cabinet range. is there a way to install a 36in hood without cutting a new hole for the duct on my house?

Comment: there is always a way to do something ... you provided near zero information about your situation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you can remove the filters and look inside, you may be able to work out exactly where and how large the duct boot is, then try to match your new range hood to it.  In the case of the one I just installed, there are also usually more than one possible exit.

If they are the same brand, it is likely that the duct openings will be in similar places.  Might even been the same guts in a different width box.

Do you have a model number for the existing hood?  Installation manuals are usually available online and you might be able to get the specs and location of the duct opening from there.

Comment: the problem is to center the new hood it would need to be moved over about 2-3 inches to the left if you are facing the range. The brand that is there is a cheap home depot one that has very low cfm

Comment: Without seeing what cabinets etc are by the existing hood I really cannot guess what you are getting into. Some pictures would definitely help. One relative close but sure the whole hood is in. One further back showing the adjoining cabinets etc. If you remove the filters one showing how it is mounted.